# VerifyError when using Instant Run

Tags: android, instant-run

A `VerifyError` is thrown when `XpInsetDrawable.create(Drawable, int)` (code below) is reached. This does not happen when *not* using Instant Run.

I'm using Android Studio 2.0.0 and gradle build plugin 2.0.0. Tested on SDK 22. When run on SDK 19 emulator the whole emulator restarts.

I'm looking for a solution other than "disable Instant Run".

**Exception** (whole stack trace is unrelated)

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError:
Verifier rejected class net.xpece.android.support.preference.XpInsetDrawable due to bad method
java.lang.Object net.xpece.android.support.preference.XpInsetDrawable.access$super(
    net.xpece.android.support.preference.XpInsetDrawable,
    java.lang.String,
    java.lang.Object[])
(declaration of 'net.xpece.android.support.preference.XpInsetDrawable'
appears in /data/data/net.xpece.android.support.preference.sample/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classe
```

**Class source code**

```
final class XpInsetDrawable extends InsetDrawable {
    private static final boolean NEEDS_FIXING = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21;

    private final Rect mInset = new Rect();

    public static InsetDrawable create(final Drawable drawable, final int insetLeft, final int insetTop, final int insetRight, final int insetBottom) {
        if (NEEDS_FIXING) {
            return new XpInsetDrawable(drawable, insetLeft, insetTop, insetRight, insetBottom);
        } else {
            return new InsetDrawable(drawable, insetLeft, insetTop, insetRight, insetBottom);
        }
    }

    public static InsetDrawable create(final Drawable drawable, final int inset) {
        if (NEEDS_FIXING) {
            return new XpInsetDrawable(drawable, inset);
        } else {
            return new InsetDrawable(drawable, inset);
        }
    }

    XpInsetDrawable(final Drawable drawable, final int inset) {
        super(drawable, inset);
        mInset.set(inset, inset, inset, inset);
    }

    XpInsetDrawable(final Drawable drawable, final int insetLeft, final int insetTop, final int insetRight, final int insetBottom) {
        super(drawable, insetLeft, insetTop, insetRight, insetBottom);
        mInset.set(insetLeft, insetTop, insetRight, insetBottom);
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return super.getIntrinsicHeight() + mInset.top + mInset.bottom;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
        return super.getIntrinsicWidth() + mInset.left + mInset.right;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you filed a bug at [b.android.com](http://b.android.com)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake As suggested https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206746

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*UPDATE 2016-08-25:* Fix released in Android Studio 2.2-beta3.

---

<s>*UPDATE 2016-07-15:* Target release for fix is now Android Studio 2.3.</s>

---

I filed a bug with Android and here's what dev [j...@google.com](https://code.google.com/u/104256661071090509203/) had to say about it:

> Interesting !
>
> The XpInsetDrawable is a subclass of InsetDrawable which parent has changed in 23. Starting in 23, InsetDrawable subclasses DrawableWrapper which was added in 23. The app is compiled with CompileSdkVersion 23 so we generate method accesses for the DrawableWrapper methods.
>
> now when running on <23, these methods do no exist, in fact the class does not exist so we blow up.
>
> workaround for now is to have compileSdkVersion set to a lower version or run the application on 23 when in InstantRun mode.

and

> potential fix is to instrument against the targeted device API level android.jar rather than the compileSdkVersion one. This is too involving for 2.1, targeted to 2.2.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206746

---

This means that I can't subclass `InsetDrawable` and use Instant Run at the same time until Android Studio 2.2 is released.

I'll look into copying SDK 22 `InsetDrawable` directly into my project.